# How can I forbid user to resize the window in WINUI 3.0?

Tags: winui-3

How can I forbid user to resize the window in WINUI 3.0?
I find that the `this.AppWindow.Resizable` property donot exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
private AppWindow _apw;
private OverlappedPresenter _presenter;

public void GetAppWindowAndPresenter() {
    var hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
    WindowId myWndId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);
    _apw = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(myWndId);
    _presenter = _apw.Presenter as OverlappedPresenter;
}
```

In constructor:

```
GetAppWindowAndPresenter();
_presenter.IsResizable = false;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).